# Function to check if version string is newer (1.2.5 > 1.1.10 for example)

Tags: php

I'm looking for a simple function that checks 2 version strings to each other.
What I've done now is explode it on the . and check each number from right to left. But I feel like it could be a lot simpler.

Hope to hear.
Kind regards,
Kevin Walter

Comment: Any sample code?

Comment: `checks 2 version strings to each other`? Post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt, noting input and expected output

Comment: Why not check from left to right?

Comment: Reading it back this was the worst post I've ever done here. Sorry. I'll add the information. Let's just say it's monday morning.....

Answer (score 7):

There is the php function to do that: [version_compare](http://php.net/manual/en/function.version-compare.php)

```
var_dump(version_compare('1.2.5', '1.1.10'));
```

Comment: Well, you got a +1 from me for actually being able to understand the question as it is ^^

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the answer. And I'm so sorry for the terrible question!